Цикл перекрывает работу бота PYTHON
создаю бота на Python c библиотекой telebot, нужно сделать цикл, который будет работать каждые 5 минут, через while не хочется делать сделал через scheduler но этот код работает и не дает боту запуститься, как это можно реализовать, сам код:
def check_passed_events():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('leader_database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    current_date = datetime.now().date()

    query = "SELECT event_date, events_passed FROM Events"
    cursor.execute(query)
    events = cursor.fetchall()

    for event in events:
        event_date = parse(event[0]).date()
        events_passed = event[1]

        if event_date < current_date:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE Events SET events_passed = 1 WHERE event_date = ?", (event[0],))
            print(f"Updated events_passed for event on {event[0]}")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print("CHECKED")

    # Планирование следующего запуска через 5 минут
    scheduler.enter(300, 1, check_passed_events)

# Первоначальный запуск функции
scheduler.enter(0, 1, check_passed_events)
scheduler.run()


Это происходит из-за того, что scheduler.run() блокирует основной поток, он отрабатывает задачу и ждёт следующую. Внутри метода run() можно указать blocking=False, он выполнит действие, если время подошло или вернет время до следующего события, но в таком случае вам надо будет самому вызывать scheduler.run(), либо думать как это всё дело делать асинхронно. Почему бы просто не запускать этот скрипт в отдельном файле, если функция не принимает никаких аргументов и не взаимодействует никак с ботом?

Или просто создать Treading.
